# How to detect if the user has read all the text?

Tags: java, jeditorpane

I would like to force the user to read (at least scroll to the bottom of) all the text inside a `javax.swing.JEditorPane`. This editor pane has a `JScrollPane`, that can only add a vertical slider, if the text is too long to display. The text is not fixed length it can be one sentence (where it is already displayed on the page) or several pages long (then theuser has to scroll down with the slider).

There is a button, that the user can press, if he acknowledges the text. **What can I write into the button's onclick event, that will test if the user has read all the text?**

Edit: To check if the user scrolled to the bottom of the editor pane is fine. The scroll bar is not present in all cases.

Thanks for the help, Sziro.

Comment: "Did you *really* read all the text?" Honestly ... how can the computer know if the user did do it?

Comment: You're not going to be able to know if the user *actually* read the text. Some EULAs I've seen have checked that you've scrolled to the very bottom, which *implies* you've read it, but nearly everyone is just scrolling quickly to the bottom and then hitting `Agree`. This is about as good as you can get without being overly obnoxious to the user.

Comment: at most you can detect when the user has scrolled to the end of the text. It is literally impossible to check if they've actually READ anything.

Comment: At least if the user scrolled to the bottom. It is enough :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tto find out if the user has scrolled to the bottom of the pane, try:

```
if (editorPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum() == 
    editorPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue())
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want your users to hate you, you could check the JScrollPane's vertical position against the height of the JEditorPane.

Comment: and if you want user to hate you more... add a timer xD

Comment: Followed by a short quiz!